# Flag Enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an Enum defined as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum Number
{
    first=1,
    second=2,
    third=4,
    Forth=8,
    fifth=16,
    six=Number.second|Number.first,
    seven=Number.second|Number.first|Number.third

}
```

I know it is possible to combine the enums values.

For Example:

```
Number number1 = Number.first;
number1 |= Number.second;
```

Now, number1 is equivalent to Number.six

```
number1 |=Number.third
```

Now, number1 is equivalent to Number.seven

After this,

I want to get number1 equivalent to Number.six

Now my question is :

Is it possible to do the **reverse** the OR, making the number1 contain only  Number.first and Number.second rather Number.first,Number.second and Number.third.

I am new to Flag Enums and not sure if anything like this is possible.

Comment: Try `number1 &= ~Number.third` - but I'm not sure that this will work with enums but I guess it.

Comment: Flag enums are not different to just enums, and just enums are just integers.

Comment: Thanks "Vera rind" this works.

Comment: This is not about flag enums. You never bothered to learn boolean arithmetic - which is the core of a lot of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like `number1 = number1 & Number.first` which would eliminate **every** other value than `Number.first` and if `number1` does not have `Number.first` it gets `0`.

Also consider using `number1.HasFlag(Number.first)` as it is often much more readable than the logical operations to check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `&` it with the `~` (complement) of `Number.third`

```
number1 &= ~Number.third;
```

Comment: Already answered in the comment by "Vera rind"